# Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development, works localy tho

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a weird error that has been bugging me for a while now.  When I run the server local the site shows up perfect but when I try to access it on my aws EC2 I get the error "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development"
So I ran the command "bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development" and this prints out.

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
Running via Spring preloader in process 30908
== 20160812175638 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:posts)
   -> 0.0014s
== 20160812175638 CreatePosts: migrated (0.0017s) =============================

== 20160813194710 DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0015s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0005s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0007s
== 20160813194710 DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0031s) =======================

== 20160912112653 AddAttachmentImageToPosts: migrating ========================
-- change_table(:posts)
   -> 0.0012s
== 20160912112653 AddAttachmentImageToPosts: migrated (0.0013s) ===============
```

but I still get the same msg. So I did some searching on the net and I have read all the pages here on this issue and haven't found nothing.

When I run "rake db:migrate:status" I see this:

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20160812175638  Create posts
   up     20160813194710  Devise create users
   up     20160912112653  Add attachment image to posts
```

And when I do "rake db:version" I get this:

```
Current version: 20160912112653
```

"rails -v" gives me

```
Rails 4.2.6
```

and "cat Gemfile | grep rails" gives me this:# Bundle edge Rails instead:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
```

I'm at loss here, it works just fine on local and it worked just fine if I edit away /data/ from database.rb file.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/data/development.sqlite3
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/data/production.sqlite3
```

But if I do that the database gets wiped as soon as I update the site with my redeploy script which is running docker-compose for me.

I quite sure that I've missed a simple thing that gives me this error tho since the site do work on the localhost.

//Emmoth

I think I know whats is the problem now, don't know how to fix it tho.
When I run `docker volume ls` it doesn't find any volume at all.
here is the output from `docker inspect`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48",
        "Created": "2016-10-09T16:48:24.678289811Z",
        "Path": "rails",
        "Args": [
            "server",
            "-b",
            "0.0.0.0"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 15188,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-10-09T16:48:24.925986705Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c8ccdcb3602d581c06264db2b24f99cd4f936713ca84c614c056743b8d89d459",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48/4b72d9a721f086706f53f08a88b5f32c959f6a28ec37d3396c14922c7750bc48-json.log",
        "Name": "/juridik_app_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/storage/db:/usr/src/app/db/data:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/storage/db",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app/db/data",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "4b72d9a721f0",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3000/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "S3_BUCKET_REGION=eu-europe-1",
                "S3_SECRET_KEY=*************************",
                "S3_BUCKET=juridik-assets",
                "S3_KEY_ID=*********************",
                "PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "RUBY_MAJOR=2.3",
                "RUBY_VERSION=2.3.1",
                "RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=b87c738cb2032bf4920fef8e3864dc5cf8eae9d89d8d523ce0236945c5797dcd",
                "RUBYGEMS_VERSION=2.6.6",
                "BUNDLER_VERSION=1.13.1",
                "GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle",
                "BUNDLE_PATH=/usr/local/bundle",
                "BUNDLE_BIN=/usr/local/bundle/bin",
                "BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1",
                "BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "rails",
                "server",
                "-b",
                "0.0.0.0"
            ],
            "Image": "juridik_app",
            "Volumes": {
                "/usr/src/app/db/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/usr/src/app",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "6c31573cdfdba0b4c056f7af83e652b728c4a56083a6c7eabd8634b2dbfccb47",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "juridik",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "app",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.8.0"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "de9a9bfc8196ee65d89e09dc0a41acbb1f28830229d4e53fe057832a5419a778",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/de9a9bfc8196",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "ee42a322ee7de01529408d782a93556333cf9e368934ccfe03e98c1223ae44e3",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "16145185c61bbe11c565fbbb974aefaa79db796feb80eccb98765fc67bed8158",
                    "EndpointID": "ee42a322ee7de01529408d782a93556333cf9e368934ccfe03e98c1223ae44e3",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What rails environment are you using on your EC2 instance? I'd imagine it would be `production` instead of `development`. Have you tried `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: I just tried to run that command instead and it still ask me to do the other one. I'm quite new at this and haven't encounter this type of error before that couldn't be solved by just simply running that command. So I would be thankful if you can point me in the direction to where i can find the environment that rails are using.

Comment: I'm staring to think that the error might be docker and not rails it self. 
If I run "docker volume ls" I can't see any volumes at all, so that might be the problem, not sure tho how to fix that :/ As I said I'm quite new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the net for like 3 days for an answer I got one from a friend of mine.

He told me get rid of the big red error message "pending migrations"
I had to do

```
docker-compose exec app bash
```

and inside that do

```
rake db:migrate
```

and then

```
exit
```

Which I did and then my problems where gone. So it works now as it should. Hope that someone else can benefit from this too.